# How to use specific font with highlight.js

Tags: javascript, css, highlight.js, hugo

*Updated with the proper link to the example*

I am using a Hugo theme that comes with bundled with CSS and uses Highlight.JS for syntax highlighting. The web pages I have created show a plain "courier" based fixed width font in the code blocks [see here for example of my site page](http://enterprise-cio.khan.ms/blog/hugoisforlovers/)

I would like to use another font, like sans-mono or something more neat looking, like it shows on Highlight.JS web page [here](https://highlightjs.org)

I'm not super familiar with Javascript and CSS, just trying to use them. Is there an easier way to tell Highlight.JS to use specific font? Assuming I have font files available.

Thanks
ZeeKay

Comment: You gave a link to your localhost... it's unreachable obviously.

Comment: Thanks for catching it. I updated with a relevant link.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add this to your CSS:

```css
pre > code {
    font-family: "Sans Mono", "Consolas", "Courier", monospace;
}
```

This will use the first font in that list that is available on the user’s system. Sometimes fonts have different spacing that their real names, so for example if `"Sans Mono"` doesn’t work, try `"SansMono"`. Make sure to put `monospace` last so that at least some suitable font is chosen if the user doesn’t have any of the listed fonts.

If this doesn’t work, maybe it’s due to a selector specificity problem, where the default styles provided by highlight.js are overriding your own styles. Something that will help avoid this is putting the `<link>` that loads your CSS file after the one to load the highlight.js CSS file. If this doesn’t work, you will have to make the `pre > code` selector more specific, such as changing it to `#main pre > code` if all page content is wrapped in an element with the ID `main`.

If you’re not sure how to add CSS, the easiest way is to put it in the HTML template surrounded by `<style></style>` tags. Though it’s better to put it in a CSS file and reference it with `<link rel="stylesheet" href="myStyles.css">`.

Comment: Thank you @rory-okane for the tip. I ended up changing the font line to: 

`font-family: "Monaco", "Consolas", "Ubuntu Mono", "Courier New", monospace;`

instead to display a better mono font.

But this begs the question that this line is loading the font installed locally on my computer, not the web-fonts I have bundled with my site. How do I force the usage of web-fonts here? This is important as I need it to be consistent across platforms.

Thanks again!

Comment: @ZeeKay After you load a web-font on a site, it becomes referenceable in `font-family` by the name specified in the web-font. Check the documentation from where you got the web-font – you can often reference the font with the obvious name `"Sans Mono"`, but some sources require calling the font something like `"Sans+Mono"` or `"SansMono_400"` instead. You should still specify locally-available fallback fonts later in the list – they will be used while the web-font is loading.